# Apache Camel:RabbitMQ Requeing a message to the same queue causes duplication of message

Tags: duplicates, rabbitmq, apache-camel

I'm doing something like

```
  from(rabbitmq:pollingQueue?prefetchSize=1&concurrentConsumer=10)
        .process(pollingRequestStatus) // check status of the request, if not ready, requeue = true
        .Choice
           .when(requeue == true) // request not ready
           .to(rabbitmq:pollingQueue)//back to the same queue
        .endChoice
        .otherwise
        .to(proceedToSomethingElse)
        .endChoice.end;
```

When the requeue happens, the message gets duplicated, is this an expected behavior when sending back the message to the same queue?

I have also tried something like the following as suggested but it does not work,the message seems to be just consumed and won't requeue

```
from(rabbitmq:pollingQueue? prefetchSize=1&concurrentConsumer=10)
     .onException(NotReadyException.class)
     .handled(true)
     .setHeader(RabbitMQConstants.REQUEUE, constant(true))
     .end() 
     .process(pollingRequestStatus) // check status of the request, if not ready, throw NotReadyEception
        .to(proceedToSomethingElse);
```

The other two ways i have tried that at least does not create duplicates,

1.) on NotReadyExeption, send the message back to the pollingQueue

```
from(rabbitmq:pollingQueue? prefetchSize=1&concurrentConsumer=10)
    .onException(NotReadyException.class)
    .to(rabbitmq:pollingQueue)
    //.delay(constant(8000)) //not sure why it throws error if i set delay
    .end
    .process(pollingRequestStatus); // check status of the request, if not ready, throw NotReadyEception
```

This works, however, it runs too quick, like instantly.
If i set delay(constant(number)), the following error is thrown,

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route13 at: >>> From [bla bla bla...]
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:1062)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:196)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRoute(DefaultCamelContext.java:984)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:3401)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:3132)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.access$000(DefaultCamelContext.java:183)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2961)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2957)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWithDefinedClassLoader(DefaultCamelContext.java:2980)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:2957)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:2924)
    at com.mbww.ithink.runner.Main.main(Main.java:174)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Route route13 has no output processors. You need to add outputs to the route such as to("log:foo").
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:1060)
```

2.) On NotReadyException, redeliver based on redeliveryPolicy

```
from(rabbitmq:pollingQueue? prefetchSize=1&concurrentConsumer=10)
    .onException(NotReadyException.class)
    .setFaultBody(constant(false))
    .maximumRedeliveries(-1) // -1 = redeliver forever
    .redeliveryDelay(10000)
    .end
    .process(pollingRequestStatus); // check status of the request, if not ready, throw NotReadyEception
```

Originally the idea of requeue is so that if the request is not ready, requeue the message to be back of the queue, set a delay and check the status of the next request, and avoid getting things like Ratelimit error.
seems like the redelivery policy is the way to go now.

Thanks

Comment: which camel version are you using?

Comment: @jfneis  camel version 2.18.3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To be able to requeue the message you have to turn off RabbitMQ's auto-acknowledgement. In that case you have to manually send the `ack`, `nack` or `reject` message back to the publisher. (https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html)

It means you have to manually call one of the `basicAck`, `basicNack` or `basicReject` function on the current `Channel` implementation.

---

### Translated to Camel:

To turn of auto-acknowledgement add the `autoAck=false` to the endpoint parameters.

AFAIK, the Camel Endpoint's underlying Channel is not accessible ([source](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-rabbitmq/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/rabbitmq/RabbitConsumer.java#L39)) so you can't directly call the Channel's `basicReject(long deliveryTag, boolean requeue)` function, but Camel does call it when the exchange is failed (exception occured during to routing).

The workaround might be the following: (pseudocodish and I haven't tried it, but based on checking the `camel-rabbitmq` endpoint's source, especially [this](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-rabbitmq/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/rabbitmq/RabbitConsumer.java#L152) part)

### Updated workaround (tested and working):

```
from("rabbitmq://localhost:5672/first?queue=test&concurrentConsumers=10prefetchSize=1&autoAck=false&autoDelete=false")
            .onException(NotReadyException.class)
                .log("Error for ${body}! Requeue")
                .asyncDelayedRedelivery().redeliveryDelay(5000) // wait 5 secs to redeliver and requeue
                .maximumRedeliveries(1)
                .setHeader(RabbitMQConstants.REQUEUE, constant(true))
                .handled(true)
                .setFaultBody(constant(true))
            .end()
            .log("Received: ${body}")
            .process((e) -> {
                if(notReady(e))
                    throw new NotReadyException(); // create a new Exception and throw it if the status is not ready
                }
            })
            .to("direct:somethingElse");
```

Also I created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/mgyongyosi/fa71a52da65a9dd3cddd537fb4feca66) which implements almost a same scenario. 
Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi @mgyongyosi thanks for the findings, unfortunately it doesn't work, not sure if i have misconfigured anything. Also, i updated my post, you can take a look my other finding.

Comment: Hi, I've updated my answer with a working workaround (I tested it and it works). Also I created an example gist on requeuing: [check here](https://gist.github.com/mgyongyosi/fa71a52da65a9dd3cddd537fb4feca66)

Comment: Hi, I'm using a similar mechanism, basically the asyndelayredelivery, the only difference is, I did not set the RabbitMQConstants.REQUEUE, and the redelivery will still work fine, not sure if it will behave differently of I set it. Will try it out when I have the time. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to send the message again, just set rabbitmq.REQUEUE property to true. If this property is set, rabbitmq component will automatically requeue the message instead of discarding it. From [the docs](http://camel.apache.org/rabbitmq.html):

> Camel 2.14.2: This is used by the consumer to control rejection of the
>   message. When the consumer is complete processing the exchange, and if
>   the exchange failed, then the consumer is going to reject the message
>   from the RabbitMQ broker. The value of this header controls this
>   behavior. If the value is false (by default) then the message is
>   discarded/dead-lettered. If the value is true, then the message is
>   re-queued.

So, inside your processor you can do something like:

```
exchange.getIn().setHeader("rabbitmq.REQUEUE", true);
```

And then just check REQUEUE header == false in your route to call `proceedToSomethingElse`.

Comment: @laiyokehman can you please update your question with your code?

Comment: The `rabbitmq.REQUEUE` only works in case the "exchange failed".